# C code crashes from memmove

Tags: c, memmove

My code does not crash when I write:

```
char s[44] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
memmove(s, "asdf", 5);
```

But it does when I write:

```
char* s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
memmove(s, "asdf", 5);
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: did you get segmentation fault? are you compiling with gcc?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Comment: Trying to modify a string literal is Undefined Behaviour. In your case, apparently, the UB makes your program crash; in another computer it might change the contents of the string literal; in yet another computer it might make lemon juice ooze out of the USB port.

Answer (score 8):

first one allocates space and puts the a's in

second one is a pointer to constant memory,  you aren't allowed to change it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, 44 bytes are allocated on stack and the string "aa..a" is copied to this space. But in the second space, the string "aa..a" is a constant value and stored in the read only data segment. So a page fault will occur when you try to write a read only memory address.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:Yes, more specifically, SIGSEGV sigal in UNIX

Answer (score 1):

`char* s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";`

the string constant "aaaa" whatever is stored in a the memory which is readonly. For example in elf executables they will be stored in the `.rodata` section, which is nor writable. Therefore when you attempt to write at such a location it results in an errorhe

On the other hand `char s[]` will have the string stored in the local stack area, which you can modify.